# QGIS: permanent layer of vertices is invisible

Tags: qgis

I'm working in QGIS, and I've extracted the vertices from a .shp file of polygons. If I make the vertices into a temporary layer, the points are visible and I can remove them as I please. However, this is risky because exiting QGIS means that the temporary layer gets removed.

I then tried making a permanent layer out of the vertices, but the points will not show up on my screen. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you able to view data in the attribute table ?

Comment: Don't save the points as csv. Save them to a shapefile.

Comment: Ok, will try it out. Thanks for the advice

Comment: What do you mean by not associated? Can you please explain?

Comment: This is looking like a different question than the initial one. The initial one was answered in the comment and I will add a proper answer to it so you can accept it. And in keeping with the guidelines of the site of one question per post, I would ask you to post a new question and explain what is it that you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. One note though, I would consider the CSV file as an output rather than a working file.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the OP was saving his temporary layer to a CSV which removes the geometry, rendering the points invisible. As long as the geometry is needed, the data should be saved in a format that supports geometry such as a shapefile, as it also supports editing.